# Rename copied objects with attached increment (i.e. NewObject_1)

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, treeview

I am currently working on a `WinForms` application using a `Treeview` control. I have added a copy-mechanism to duplicate the currently selected `Treenode`.
The names of the copied `Treenode` objects should be different from the original `Treenode` in the following manner:
"aNode",
"aNode_1",
"aNode_2".

It feels like `Regex` is the way to go.

Here is what i've got so far:

```
string theNameToBe = "aName";
List<string> theAlreadyInUseNames   // Filled beforehand
int i = 1;
do
{
    // ToDo: Use Regex to get XXXXX_1 -> XXXXX_2 as a possible name instead of XXXXX_1_1
    Regex aPossibleNewNameRegex = new Regex( String.Format("^{0}[_]\\d+$", theNameToBe),RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // This does not take a previously created XXXXX_1 into account and continues to attach "_1"s to the string
    string thePossibleNewName = String.Format( theNameToBe + "_{0}", i );

    if ( !theAlreadyInUseNames.Any( s => s.Equals( thePossibleNewName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ) )
    {
        theNextAvailableName = thePossibleNewName;
        break;
    }

    i++;
} while ( i < int.MaxValue );
```

This only gets subsequent Names like "aNode", "aNode_1", "aNode_1_1", ... and so on.

Can you please help me with my lack of expertise in handlin regular expressions in `C#`?

Edit to clarify:
The next available empty spot should be determined. When later on one of the Nodes/Names is deleted there is a vacant spot. So if only the strings "aName", "aName_1" and "aName_3" are present "aName_2" is the correct finding.

Comment: Are you renaming or generating names? Because generating is as simple as `$"{name}_{i++}"`.

Comment: It's about determining the next available spot. Like after deleting aName_2 the next copied node should be inserted between aName_1 and aName_3 rather than simply adding up another one and name it aName_4.
Good Point, thanks. I'll try to clarify that in the question.

Comment: Question is not clear.
What you have (with example)? and what you want to get?

Comment: After a bit of deleting, adding and copying lets assume the list of entries is as such:
aNode, aNode_1, aDefaultNode, aNode_3, aNode_New
Then you select aNode_1 and copy it. The new name Should be aNode_2. What i get is aNode_1_1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have found a solution that fulfills the requirements. This is the first draft and may be updated after a round of unittests and real life scenarios.
And there is always the possibility that this version is way to complex for the job and Sinatrs slim approach might be adequate.

```
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        List<string> theAlreadyInUseNames = new List<string>();

        theAlreadyInUseNames.Add( "aName" );
        theAlreadyInUseNames.Add( "aName_1" );
        theAlreadyInUseNames.Add( "aName_2" );
        theAlreadyInUseNames.Add( "aName_3" );
        theAlreadyInUseNames.Add( "aName_4" );
        theAlreadyInUseNames.Add( "aName_5" );
        theAlreadyInUseNames.Add( "aName_7" );
        theAlreadyInUseNames.Add( "aName_2_1" );
        theAlreadyInUseNames.Add( "aName_2_3" );

        string theNameToBe0 = "aName";
        string theNameToBe1 = "aName_2";
        string theNameToBe2 = "aName_2_1";

        List<string> namesToBe = new List<string>();
        namesToBe.Add( theNameToBe0 );
        namesToBe.Add( theNameToBe1 );
        namesToBe.Add( theNameToBe2 );

        string[] splits;
        char[] charSeparators = new char[] { '_' };
        string theNewNameToBe1 = string.Empty;
        string theNextAvailableName = String.Empty;

        foreach ( var item in namesToBe )
        {
            splits = item.Split( charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );


            if ( splits.Length > 1 )
            {
                int theNumber = Convert.ToInt32( splits.Last() );

                theNewNameToBe1 = splits.ElementAt( 0 );

                for ( int i = 1; i < splits.Length - 1; i++ )
                {
                    theNewNameToBe1 = theNewNameToBe1 + "_" + splits.ElementAt( i );
                }

                int counter = 1;
                string theActualNewName = string.Empty;
                do
                {

                    theActualNewName = theNewNameToBe1 + "_" + ( theNumber + counter );

                    if ( !theAlreadyInUseNames.Any( s => s.Equals( theActualNewName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ) )
                    {
                        theNextAvailableName = theActualNewName;
                        break;
                    }

                    counter++;
                } while ( counter < int.MaxValue );
            }
            else if ( splits.Length == 1 )
            {
                    int counter = 1;
                    string theActualNewName = string.Empty;

                    do
                    {
                        theActualNewName = theNameToBe + "_" + ( counter );

                        if ( !theAlreadyInUseNames.Any( s => s.Equals( theActualNewName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ) )
                        {
                            theNextAvailableName = theActualNewName;
                            break;
                        }

                        counter++;
                    } while ( counter < int.MaxValue );
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as

```
var selected = "node_3";
var names = new[] { "node_1", "node_3" };
var prefix = selected.Substring(0, selected.IndexOf('_') + 1);
var number = 1;
string name; // result
do
    name = prefix + number++;
while (names.Contains(name));
```